# How can I read ".on()" method arguments in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no idea how to bite this problem. Below two examples are working great but I want to avoid the *DRY* problem.

```
parentElement.on('focusout', '.foo-class', function () {
    // console.log('hello foo')
});
```

and:

```
parentElement.on('focusout', '.bar-class', function () {
    // console.log('hello bar')
});
```

I would like to make it more universal. I have to deal with two classes while the parent stays the same.

Assuming that this is the first step:

```
parentElement.on('focusout', classValue, function () {
    // How to display this class so I can call different stuff depending on the class value?
    // console.log('hello ' + classValue)
});
```

Comment: Would `if $(this).hasClass(class1) { /* do stuff for class 1 */ }` work?

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pvorhknv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something along these line, refined from guardio's solution.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvorhknv/2/

What it doing here is to get the element been called for the handler and accessing the attributes. You can use this element "this" for any such use.

```
$(document).on('focusout', 'input', callme);

function callme(){
   console.log('hello ' + $(this).attr('class').split('-')[0])
}
```

UPDATE:

One other thing you can use it to mark data attribute for the elements. 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvorhknv/3/

```
<input type='text' class='foo-class' data-classname="foo">
<input type='text' class='bar-class' data-classname="bar">
```

And hence you can access them,

```
function callme(){
   console.log('hello ' + $(this).data('classname'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of not providing multiple class names.

Answer (score 0):

To look if the **(1) element has a particular class**, and to **(2) get all classes of $(this)**, see following:

```
parentElement.on('focusout', classValue, function () {
    // (1). find out if element has class 'foo-class'
    if $(this).hasClass('foo-class'){
      // ...
    }

    // (2). for each class of element do something
    $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() { 
        if (this !== '') {
            // ...
        }    
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute for specify event which you want to run. My solution is below (simple nothing more nothing less):

html

```
<div class="event" data-color-event="blue">click me = blue</div>
```

js

```
   // one listener 
   $('body').on('click', '.event', function() {
        var ev = $(this).data('color-event');
      $('body')[ev]();
    });

    // event functions on demand
    $.fn.blue = function() {
        alert('blue');
    }

    $.fn.red = function() {
        alert('red');
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yf5sfd5k/)

Answer (score 0):

Separate your classes with commas, and then check the class in the callback.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/dmpgxxt0/

```
$('.container').on('click','.test1,.test2',function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
parentElement.on('focusout', '.foo-class, .bar-class', function () {
// console.log('hello foo')
});
```

And more:

```
parentElement
    .on('focusout', '.foo-class, .bar-class', function () {
        // console.log('hello foo')
    })
    .on('click', '.baz-class', function() { alert('xx'); })
;
```